# Jest snapshots for react native static images throwing warnings

Tags: react-native, jestjs, snapshot

I am trying to write snapshots tests to check if the correct image is being returned.  When I just use zero transforms than the result is always '1' which isnt very helpful.  I went onto the site and added this to my package.json

```
"transform": {
  "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/jest/fileTransformer.js"
}
```

and create a file called fileTransformer that looks like this

```
    // fileTransformer.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  process(src, filename, config, options) {
    return 'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename)) + ';';
  },
};
```

Now the tests are resulting in useful snapshots which is great, however im not getting warnings in my console that look like this

```
console.error node_modules/prop-types/checkPropTypes.js:20
      Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`.
          in Image
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [`moduleNameMapper`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string) configuration

```
"^[./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\\.png$": "<rootDir>/RelativeImageStub.js",
```

and inside the file you can export a dummy image path

**`RelativeImageStub.js`**

```
export default '/dummy/path/to/dummyImage.png';
```

---

You should also be able to mock the result from importing the image:

**`Component.spec.js`**

```js
import Component from './Component';

jest.mock('./path/to/the/image.png', () => "dummy/path/image.png");
```

**`Component.js`**

```
import image from './path/to/the/image.png';

export default function Component() {
  return <Image source={image} />;
}
```

This way you'll also get an error if the specified path does not exists.

Comment: i found it worked with just 

jest.mock('./path/to/the/image.png', () => "dummy/path/image.png");


I didnt need to add the relativeImageStub

Comment: It's the one or the other, the first approach will be global for all of the tests, as the second one will be just for the current file

Comment: thanks i never realised you meant that when you originally posted the answer, thanks so much this helped a ton